# Convert any Recursive Summation into an Integral

Tags: integration, summation, closed-form, recursion, recursive-algorithms

My goal is to solve a recursive summation without iteration (a lot to ask for I know). 
Is there a technique for converting a recursive summation into an integral?

For example, these two recursive summations:
$$
F_n = \sum_{k=n-1}^{n}  F_k
$$

$$
L_{x} = \sum_{t=0}^{180} \sum_{k=x+t}^{1000}  L_k
$$

How can I turn either of these into an integral or a closed form equation? I'm specifically interested in the second (double summation) example.

Better yet, is there a universal solution for turning any arbitrary recursive summation into integral form?

Comment: You can get an integral representation for the Fibonacci numbers by following the path (recurrence relation) > (generating function) > (Cauchy integral formula). Is that the kind of thing you're looking for?

Comment: Possibly. Can I do this for a double summation such as in the second example? What are the limitations of such summations/functions I can do this for?

Comment: In principle, if you can find a generating function then you can find an integral representation.

Comment: Is there a basic example you can direct me to (or briefly illustrate yourself) that shows the process of the three steps you listed? (Recurrence relation) > (Generating function) > (Cauchy integral formula)

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Power_series) for the steps to obtain the generating function $s(x)$ for the Fibonacci numbers. Then, since $F_n = s^{(n)}(0)/n!$, apply the Cauchy integral formula for higher derivatives (called [Cauchy's differentiation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula#Theorem) on wikipedia) using an appropriately small circle $\gamma$, say the circle $|x| = 1/2$, to obtain an integral representation for $s^{(n)}(0)$ and hence $F_n$.